# Unable to get the metrics from heapster pod in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, heapster

I am trying to get the metrics in Kubernetes dashboard. For that I'm running the `influxdb` and `heapster` pod in my `kube-system` namespace. I checked the status of pods using the command `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`. Here is the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/tree/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb) which I was followed  But heapster shows the logs as

```
E1023 13:41:07.915723       1 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/util/util.go:30: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

Could anybody suggest where might be I will do the changes in my configurations?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes do you use?

Comment: Hello  Artem Golenyaev. Here is my kubernetes version: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:46:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:36:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the heapster cannot talk to you kube-apiserver through the `kubernetes` service on your default `namespace`. A few of things, you can try:

1. Check that the service is defined in the default namespace:

   ```
   $ kubectl get svc kubernetes
   NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
   kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   92d
   ```
2. Check that all your kube-proxy pods are running ok:

   ```
   $ kubectl -n kube-system -l=k8s-app=kube-proxy get pods
   NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
   kube-proxy-xxxxx   1/1     Running   0          4d18h
   ...
   ```
3. Check that all your overlay pods are running. For example for calico

   ```
   $ kubectl -n kube-system -l=k8s-app=calico-node get pods
   NAME                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
   calico-node-88fgd   2/2     Running   3          4d21h
   ...
   ```

Comment: Hello Rico. My network and kube-proxy pods are running fine. Logs of my heapster pod is like `l.go:30: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp: i/o timeout
E1126 20:24:51.787821       1 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/util/util.go:30: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.default on 10.96.0.10:53: dial udp 10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout
`. I gave cluster admin access to heapster service account. Can you please suggest me inorder to resolve this issue?.

Comment: do you have a `kubernetes` service on the default namespace?  `kubectl get svc`

Comment: Yes Rico. My `kubernetes` service is in default namespace.